# display data according to the row number in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table and some animals have more than 10 rows of data. For a particular animal (animals_key) how can display a particular row. In our example lets say row 2.

[image: Animal Breeding table]

Comment: What is your logic by which the green record is the "second" one?  You need to tell Postgres an ordering.

Comment: The data is display in descending order. A random value (integer value) is given by a user, and that value of the record needs to be pulled out

Comment: Should specify a `PRIMARY KEY`/`UNIQUE KEY` to uniquely select a single row...

Comment: Animals_key and Soc_code acts as primary key and foreign keys

Comment: `(animals_key,  soc_code)` can **not** be a primary key as there are obviously duplicates in your result. Why doesn't that table _have_  a primary key that lets you uniquely identify each row?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()` here with a partition on the animal and a descending ordering based on the `pcnt` column.

```
select
    t.soc_code,
    t.animals_key,
    t.breed,
    t.pcnt,
    t.create_method,
    t.create_date,
    t.create_user_id
from
(
    select t.*, row_number() over (partition by animals_key order by pcnt desc) rn
    from your_table t
    where animals_key = 211004650
) t
where t.rn = 2;
```